# WCF Webservice Performance Issues on Binary Upload

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis, wsdl

I have created a simple WCF Webservice project in Visual Studio (C#). The intension behind is to create an Azure Cloud Webservice in further steps. But, I got stuck on a performance issue. The Webservice project is working very well in basicHttpBinding and I am able to establish a communication between client and server. But I have two methods that differ in performance behaviour. The first method looks like:

```
byte [] Read(int count);
```

The other method:

```
void Write(byte[] Array);
```

The Read method is very performant and needs some milliseconds for being executed. (Even with a large byte array as return value)
The Write method needs almost 3 seconds for its execution. The size of the Array parameter doesn't matter. Even if it is empty it needs this 3 seconds. Is there a Limit on upload bandwidth in IIS that causes this imperformance? Has anybody an idea what could cause this problem?

Regards
Nils